# Class File Editor "Source not found" in the default Java library?

Tags: java, eclipse

I was working on a different computer, and exported my code as an archive file, downloaded it here at home, unzipped it and imported it. Everything seemed to be fine, until I found I was getting a null pointer exception pointing to my use of random here:

```
private final Random random = new Random();

protected void generateLevel() {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            tiles[x + y * width] = random.nextInt(4);
        }
    }
}
```

It is telling me that the variable random is returning null, and when I control+click on the Random() it gives me a screen with Class File Editor source not found, [here](https://gyazo.com/404489f9b16c195f228f265cb22e3f2a) is a screenshot. I can't seem to understand the problem. Why can it not find the source of a file from within the default java library? Is there a way to fix this without re-writing my program?

UPDATE:
So I was asked for the full stack trace so here it is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.josh.game.level.RandomLevel.generateLevel(RandomLevel.java:16)
at com.josh.game.level.Level.<init>(Level.java:14)
at com.josh.game.level.RandomLevel.<init>(RandomLevel.java:10)
at com.josh.game.Game.<init>(Game.java:46)
at com.josh.game.Game.main(Game.java:136)
```

Here are all of the functions that are being shown in this error, but none of them SHOULD be returning null... (I guess that's kind of obvious though)

RandomLevel function (I decided just to throw in the whole thing)

```
public class RandomLevel extends Level {

private final Random random = new Random();

public RandomLevel(int width, int height) {
    super(width, height);
}

protected void generateLevel() {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            tiles[x + y * width] = random.nextInt(4);
        }
    }
}
```

Level constructor

```
    public Level(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    tiles = new int[width * height];
    generateLevel();
}
```

Game constructor

```
    public Game() {
    Dimension size = new Dimension(width * scale, height * scale);
    setPreferredSize(size);

    screen = new Screen(width, height);
    frame = new JFrame();
    key = new Keyboard();
    level = new RandomLevel(64, 64);
    player = new Player(key);

    addKeyListener(key);
}
```

main function

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.frame.setResizable(false);
          game.frame.setTitle(Game.title);
          game.frame.add(game);
          game.frame.pack();
          game.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          game.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          game.frame.setVisible(true);

        game.start();
    }
```

Any other code needed, I can provide. I have gone through and made sure that as far as I can tell, all variables are being instantiated before calling, so I can't quite tell. I assumed, probably wrongly, that the problem had to do with my not being able to find source for the Random class, but I guess not?

Comment: The value returned by `new` is never null, by specification. There are some contrived cases where `random` could be null (basically: during class initialization, before `random` is initialized); but you'd need to show exactly how the other line is invoked.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @Josh thanks, but you'd need to show how *that* code invoked too. Is that invoked during class initialization?

Comment: Are you running your application using a JDK or a JRE? Only the JDK would automatically have sources associated with the standard runtime jars.

Comment: @nitind I'm just using the default in eclipse. I believe its a JRE, but I'm not sure to be honest. Right now I am not at my computer at home, but I didn't want to leave this without a response for another 8 hours.

Comment: @nitind okay so yes, it is indeed the JRE, but I haven't changed anything since my previous projects, and this never happened before.

Comment: What's the fully qualified name of that `Random` type?

Comment: @nitind I seem to have fixed the problem, it needed to be a static variable. I honestly have no idea how that fixed it, but it seems to have worked. If you have an idea, that would be awesome, but that's not needed.